# jQuery POST data not being sent

Tags: php, jquery

For some reason the data `skip` is not being sent through:

main.php

```
  var skipCounter = 0;

  $('#load-more-comments').click(function(){

    skipCounter++;
    postid = <?php echo $_GET['t']; ?>;

    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'morecomments?t='+postid+'.php',
      data: {skip:skipCounter},
      success: function(data){
        $('.comments-main').append(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

morecomments.php

```
$skip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['skip']);
$postid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['t']);
```

`$skip` is null I believe, as when I manually set it to `1` instead of through POST data my code (beneath) works. The actual request is successful though.

What can cause this?

Comment: I think`url` should be `'morecomments.php?t=....` instead of `'morecomments?t=....php`, though I'm not sure if this is causing your problem.

Comment: In my .htaccess file I've changed it to remove .php from the URL, so it doesn't matter

Comment: damn well I just gave it a go, and it seemed to fix it. Weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url` should be `'morecomments.php?t=<....>` instead of `'morecomments?t=<....>.php`

Even though you have a .htaccess that removes the .php part,  it is still an invalid URL and that means that the rewrite might be removing more than you want, or the server is just rejecting part of it all together.

Comment: This fixes it, so I guess it doesn't send `POST` data through without the `.php`, but still loads the data from the url.